# Imprimir Matriz

Tags: c++, array, matrices

Cuando imprimo esta matriz, deberia de salir vertical, como salen los 1s, pero me sale todo en linea recta. Pero si despues del `cout << char(254);`pongo un `endl` me sale con espacios entre cada caracter y no juntos.

```
if (x == 1) {
    int figuras_1[4][4]{
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 }

    };
    for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
        //cout << endl;
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            if (figuras_1[f][c] == 1) {
                cout << char(254);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando hago eso tampoco me sale, nose porque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba haciendo de este modo. Se imprimen uno abajo del otro, sin saltar lineas.

```
if (x == 1) {
    int figuras_1[4][4]{
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 }

    };
        for (int f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            if (figuras_1[f][c] == 1) {
                if(f>0)
                    cout << "\n";
                cout <<  static_cast<char>(254) ;
               }
            } 

        }
    }
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado:]

Comment: Sigue apareciendo un espacio entre los caracteres (aunque se vea vertical)

Comment: @FrancescoBassino Te refieres al espacio que hay en mi imagen? O te esta saltando una linea?

Comment: aja ese espacio, como hago para que se vea todo de corrido

Comment: @FrancescoBassino ese espacio es inevitable! es el espacio que sobra entre los bordes de cada renglón de consola y los caracteres que contiene .